# Subclassing SKShapeNode with Swift

Tags: cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, swift

I'm trying to subclass `SKShapeNode` with Swift. So far I've got something like this:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class STGridNode: SKShapeNode {

    init() {
        super.init()
        self.name = "STGridNode"
        self.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.11, green: 0.82, blue: 0.69, alpha: 1)
    }

}
```

In my code I want so do something along the lines of:

```
let s = STGridNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
```

So my question is - how do I implement `rectOfSize` in the initialiser for `STGridNode`? I've tried:

```
init(rectOfSize: CGPoint) {
    super.init(rectOfSize: rectOfSize);
}
```

But that gives an error: 'Could not find an overload for init that accepts the supplied arguments'

Comment: What error are you getting when you try your initialize method?

Comment: @drewag, I've updated my question with a bit more detail. Thanks :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have two problems with the code you tried:

1. `rectOfSize` in `SKShapeNode` takes a `CGSize` not a `CGPoint`
2. `rectOfSize` in `SKShapeNode` is a convenience initializer so you won't be able to call it from a subclass. You will have to call `super.init()` and implement the rect functionality yourself

You can do something like this:

```
init(rectOfSize: CGSize) {
    super.init()

    var rect = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: rectOfSize)
    self.path = CGPathCreateWithRect(rect, nil)
}
```

Comment: self.path = CGPath(rect: rect, transform: nil)