# no designated init for SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, subclass, init, skshapenode

I'm trying to create a subclass of SKShapeNode in swift as SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius) but there is no designated init for it.

Anyone have any workarounds or info about why?  I'm not sure if this is a bug or intentional.  I found this video demonstrating a workaround for SKSpriteNode but its not working for me.  https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/5695-how-to-subclass-a-skspritenode

Overall i am trying to make a subclass for an SKShapeNode that i can then subclass from again to have different versions of to easier manage my code.
TIA

Thanks Martin i found that example earlier.  It works but how would i make that into a circle instead of a rectangle?

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit


    class Player : SKShapeNode {

        override init() {
            super.init()
            self.name = "Player"
            self.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        }

        init(rectOfSize: CGSize) {
            super.init()

            var rect = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: rectOfSize)
            self.path = CGPathCreateWithRect(rect, nil)
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }
```

In Main Code

```
let playerOne = Player(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
```

Comment: Does this help: [Subclassing SKShapeNode with Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235185/subclassing-skshapenode-with-swift) ?

Comment: If the compiler croaks about a missing init it usually suggests to insert one (red dot with square). Just let it do that.

Comment: Martin.  I worked with that example earlier and got it working now but how would i make that a circle instead of a rectangle?

Comment: if you show your code, it will be clearer...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

how's this?

```
class Player: SKShapeNode {

    init(circleOfRadius: CGFloat){
        super.init()

        let diameter = circleOfRadius * 2
        self.path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: diameter, height: diameter)), nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this how it must be done to subclass SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: ....)? sprite kit really doesn't have a built in initialiser for this?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for us.

It allows you to use other convenience initializers from `SKShapeNode`, but it has weird syntax explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536826/144088

```
class CircleNode : SKShapeNode {

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    convenience init(width: CGFloat, point: CGPoint) {
        self.init()
        self.init(circleOfRadius: width/2)
        // Do stuff
     }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: I get: `"self.init" called multiple times in initalizer`