# Sprite is not showing up in scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I made a SKShapeNode subclass called Player:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

let MOVE_UP: CGFloat = 3
class Player: SKShapeNode{

    var lifePoints = 3

    init(circleOfRadius: CGFloat, fillColor: UIColor, strokeColor: UIColor) {
        super.init()
        self.fillColor = fillColor
        self.strokeColor = strokeColor
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    class func movePlayerUp(mPlayer: SKShapeNode){
        mPlayer.position.y += MOVE_UP
    }
}
```

in `GameScene` I'm trying to create a sprite of type `Player` and show it on the screen.
I have no error and the build does not fail but the sprite won't show up on the screen.
this is how I'm creating the sprite:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
   let sprite = Player(circleOfRadius: 45, fillColor: myColors.blue, strokeColor: myColors.yellow)
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)

        self.addChild(sprite)
}
```

Comment: unrelated, but a shapenode is not a sprite :)

Comment: @Fluidity lol, thanks :) It won't be called sprite it is just a test, which is not working o.O ...

Comment: You called `super.init()` instead of `super.init(circleOfRadius: circleOfRadius)` in your initializer.

Comment: @NobodyNada I get an error that says: "Must call a designated initializer of the superclass SKShapeNode"

Comment: @swiftnewbie See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28223484/3476191

Comment: are you sure it is not displaying?  set the position to 0,0 and I bet it will show in the center of the screen.  your midX mid Y is probably moving it to the top right corner of the scene, and may be getting cropped

Comment: I have posted a working solution showing the correct designated initializer + path modification.

Comment: oh yes, lol you do not actually create a circle. Unfortunately you can't access a convenience init via an override from a class inside of a library or framework, so you have to either set the path like people have mentioned, or create a secondary setup function after creating a shape using the existing convenience inits

Comment: hey there, please upvote my answer that you accepted if you don't mind :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `super.init()`... it's blank... you made your own initializer with a pram `circleOfRadius` but this means nothing to the computer *since you did nothing with it*.

Worse, is that         `super.init(circleOfRadius: circleOfRadius)` won't work either because it is not a *designated initializer*... it is a *convenience* initializer which you can't use when calling to a *super.init*

So, basically you must resort to using `super.init()` but then *change the path of the empty shape you just made`

Add this and you will get your circle:

```
self.path = CGPath.init(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: circleOfRadius*2, height: circleOfRadius*2), cornerWidth: 45, cornerHeight: 45, transform: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank, It is working. I can see the circle now

Comment: it's a problem somewhere else in your code then :{

I copied your snippet into mine and this circle appeared @swiftnewbie

Comment: it might be  aproblem with your `myColors`, also... haha I've done this, make sure your background isn't the same color as your node... and check the `zPosition` as well and that nothing is over top of it @swiftnewbie

Comment: Thanks, this is working great.