# init skshape node inside a specific class

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I create a class of kind SKShapeNode. in the class I create a ball var that implements some properties. one of the properties that I need is 'circleOfRadius' so the ball will get a specific size. I look at the question and the answer here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223484/no-designated-init-for-skshapenodecircleofradius-radius) but I don't really get it. here is my code:

```
class BallNode: SKShapeNode{

    var lastPosition: CGPoint?

    init(circleOfRadius: CGFloat){
        super.init()
        let radius = 25
        self.init(circleOfRadius: radius)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

no matter what I try I get an error. how can I init the ball size inside the class?
thanks!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: initializer cannot both delegate ('self.init') and chin to a superclass initializer (super.init)

Comment: Why are you calling self.init()?

Comment: Because I have to call the initializer 'circleOfRadius'

Comment: But you are calling it from within itself

Comment: are you sure about what you talking about? when I remove the self.init I get an error. believe me I tried all that stuff (and failed) and thats the reason why I post the question

Comment: I assume from your responses you have a radius variable in the class. I’ll assume you have called it circleOfRadius. If so you need to initialise it with self.circleOfRadius = circleOfRadius

Comment: Circleofradius is a intilaizer inside skshapenode class. I don’t really get your point here. You are not really helping...

Comment: You really need to post more code if you want someone to help.

Comment: learn about convenience inits vs designated inits

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

Comment: I already read that and still not succeed. Can you help me with that"?

Comment: yeah, simply put, circleOfRadius in a convenience init, you can't override it. To have access to existing convenience inits, you have to override all designated inits.  This does not mean you still have the ability to override the convenience init. Whatever you are doing, I would redo, and only override the designated inits

Comment: BTW, calling init twice does not make sense,  it is like starting your car when your car is already started.